# Pointer arithmetic gone wrong

Tags: c, pointers, pointer-arithmetic

I'm trying to use a `char *` to store a string and since the pointer is pointing to the memory location of the first `char` of the given string, i tried using pointer arithmetic (`ptr++`) to move on to the next char (since they are stored sequentially). However, in my example program the *size of the "string"* is 22 but when i try running a for loop as seen below, it only runs 12 times. Any idea why? Have i missed something important on how pointer arithmetic works?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  char *strVar = "testfordifferentlength";
  int i,timesCalled=0;
  printf("\nLength = %d\n\n",strlen(strVar));
  for(i=0;i <= strlen(strVar);i++){
    printf("%c",*strVar);
    strVar++;
    timesCalled++;
  }
  printf("\n\nFor loop run %d times!\n",timesCalled);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve or learn here?

Comment: Another thing not mentioned yet is that you don't want to do `printf("%c"` on a null terminator

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is that you're calling `strlen(strVar)` on every condition check (inefficient as-is), and also modifying where `strVar` points at the same time. Store the initial size in a variable and compare your index against the initial size, rather than the remaining length of the string. Also, you probably want to use `<` rather than `<=` in your condition since you're starting at 0. Otherwise, you're also iterating over the terminating `NULL` character since strings in C are null-terminated.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  char *strVar = "testfordifferentlength";
  int i, timesCalled = 0, length = strlen(strVar);
  printf("\nLength = %d\n\n",length);
  for(i = 0; i < length; i++){
    printf("%c", *strVar);
    strVar++;
    timesCalled++;
  }
  printf("\n\nFor loop run %d times!\n", timesCalled);
  return 0;
}
```

For further understanding, imagine each loop iteration with your initial code:

```
i = 0, strVar = "testfordifferentlength", length = 22, output is 't'
i = 1, strVar = "estfordifferentlength", length = 21, output is 'e'
i = 2, strVar = "stfordifferentlength", length = 20, output is 's'
i = 3, strVar = "tfordifferentlength", length = 19, output is 't'
...
i = 11, strVar = "erentlength", length = 11, output is 'e'
And this point your loop ends
```

Essentially, you'll end up printing `(strlen/2) + 1` characters, since you're increasing your index by 1 and reducing the length of the string by 1 each loop iteration.

Comment: This is the right answer. You might be able to make the issue more clear with an illustration.

Comment: Just use the `strVar` pointer like an iterator `char *p = strVar; while (*p != '\0') { ...;p++;` makes the code much simpler.

Comment: Detail: "Otherwise you're looping 1 time past the end of your string." --> In C "a _string_ is a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and including the first null character." So I'd say "Otherwise you're looping to the end of your string." with `<=`.  Whatever it is called, `i < length` is the correct test.

Comment: @John thank you for such a clear answer. I now understand what i did wrong, thank you once again!